# Content Type Prompt in List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, jquery

I have a list that has multiple content types in a SPF2010 environment.  The manager of this list is familiar with using the New dropdown menu in the ribbon bar to select a content type, but he is worried that his team may not use the correct content type when adding data to the list.  Is there a way to prompt users to select a content type when they click the "Add new item" button at the bottom of the list?  Obviously they could use the dropdown menu, but he wants the team to always be prompted.

I would prefer a solution without managed code, so jQuery or SPD solution would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the correct default content type or you could set a content type that contains just the title column so the people are obligated to pick up one.

Otherwise, better, you could add an custom action on the ribbon.

Comment: Setting a default content type would not be helpful in this scenario as different users would need to select different content types. There would be no difference in using the ribbon bar, IMO.

Would a custom action be the same as the built-in "New" button in the ribbon bar too?

Just looking for best option here, so playing devil's advocate.

Comment: Even if you build one button foreach content type and disable the default button?

Comment: That could potentially be a lot of buttons - that would be my only reservation.  Is there a URL parameter for content type to pass with custom action button?  For example:

https://portal.sharepointsite.com/List/mylist.newform?contenttype=1

Comment: yes you can do that

Comment: I would do what Salvatore said and replace the default button, but instead of a button for each content type, replace it with a dropdown.